# Clarity on Question About Continuity and Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Can someone help clarify this question for me?

> For each function, determine whether the function is continuous or not, or uniformly continuous or not, on **each** of the three intervals: $(0,1)$, $[0,1]$, $[2,\infty)$. The functions are
>    $$f(x) = \cos(x),\quad g(x) = e^x ,\quad h(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Would I not just simply need to find if each function is continuous/uniformly continuous on the entire real line? For example, I know $\cos(x)$ is uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ while $e^x$ is not uniformly continuous on all of but it is continuous. Would these statements not simply transfer over to the given intervals?

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, $\exp$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$, but it *is* uniformly continuous on any bounded interval. Actually, it's also uniformly continuous on any interval of the form $(-\infty,a]$.

Answer (score 1):

A function that is uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ is also uniformly continuos in any sub intervals.

A function that is  continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ is also  continuos in any sub intervals.

A function that is continuos but not uniformly continuos  on $\mathbb R$ if restricted to a certain sub interval can become uniformly continuos, for example $e^x$ is unif. cont. in $[0,1]$

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure I understand it fully would I be correct in saying $h(x)$ is continuous at $(0,1)$ and $[2,\infty)$ and not continuous at $[0,1]$?

Comment: yes, you are correct:  $h(x)$ is not defined on $[0,1]$, so it can't be continuous on $[0,1]$